# Find the value of k where the system will have a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

> For what value of $k$ does the  following system of equations
>   \begin{align*}x-3y&=6\\x+3z&=-3\\2x+ky+(3-k)z&=1\end{align*}
>   have a unique solution?

This is what I tried but its wrong somewhere towards the end, I need help finding out where I went wrong, thanks!

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-3&0&6\\
      1&0&3&-3\\
      2&k&3-k&1
    \end{array}
\right] $$

$$\xrightarrow{R_3-2R_2 \to R_3} \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-3&0&6\\
      1&0&3&-3\\
      0&k&24-6k&-5
    \end{array}
\right] $$

$$\xrightarrow{R_2-R_1\to R_2} \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-3&0&6\\
      1&3&3&-9\\
      0&k&24-6k&-5
    \end{array}
\right] $$

$$\xrightarrow{-\frac{1}{3}k\cdot R_2+R_3\to R_3} \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-3&0&6\\
      1&3&3&-9\\
      0&0&24-7k&-2
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Therefore when $24-7k=-2\Rightarrow k=\frac{26}{7}$ there is a unique solution.

Comment: $\det A\neq 0\implies k\neq \dfrac{-3}{2}$

Comment: You have several mistakes. First, if $k=\frac{26}{7}$, then the last line becomes (0 0 0|2) which of course has no solution. 
Second, on first step you wrote $3-k-2\cdot{3}=24-6k$ instead of $-k-3$ and also $1-2\cdot{(-3)}=-5$ instead of $7$. Try to fix this line and compute again.

Answer (score 1):

Just see that this is the matrix of a linear transformation from $T:R^3\to R^3$
Now if the matrix has rank $3$ Then the linear transformation is onto and hence nullity is $0$ i.e $$r(A)=3$$$$n(A)=0$$So when the nullity is zero this means that the kernel is trivial. so you always get a unique solution.
So just calculate $$det(A)$$ The value of k for which the $det(A) $ is non zero implies a unique solution for any $b$ in $R^3$

Comment: Im familiar with finding the determinant for a 2x2 matrix which would be by taking a cross product, but im not sure about this size of a matrix @Upstart

Comment: You don't know the determinant of a $3×3$ matrix?

Comment: oh its the same thing as the cross product, so my Det(A) = 3, so its a unique solution?

Comment: Cross product??

Comment: I think he is referring to the vector product of two vectors, which uses a determinant for the expansion